# Error when inserting users using Data Loader

Tags: data-loader

I'm trying to insert users  pulled from one org to another org using Data Loader. The user CSV file has the Federation Id as column, pulled from the source org.

Here is the error for the failed records:

**"The specified Federation ID already exists for this organization: SAML Federation ID"**

I verified all the user records to make sure that this users doesn't exist in the Org to which I'm inserting.

Comment: The user may not exist but another user may have that federation ID on their record. Is that the case or have you confirmed that no user in the system has that federation ID. Also check that there are not duplicates int he import file.

Answer (score 2):

As you already verified that their is no duplicate user inserted in that case or use detail page you find field Federation Id. This is a unique field for user object. So two records cannot be same `FederationId`. So there is a use case that your old users exist in the org has same `federationId`  as newly inserted user.

**Note:** You sholud also check deactive users. there might you will find the user with same federationId. You need to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Also check Site guest users, this is what was causing the issue for me.

Comment: I'm a bit torn on this. I'm not sure if this answer, as is, can stand on its own. This feels more like commentary on Tushar's answer. You need 50 reputation to comment on other people's questions and answers. I do think that this answer has relevant information, and would like to keep it. Can you include some more substance to your answer through an [edit]? Maybe include a sample query and a link to documentation (if any exists).